# How to split string between two separators in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, string

I know how to split using, multiple separators but I have no idea how to split a string into an array *between* two characters. So:

```
var myArray = "(text1)(text2)(text3)".split(???)
//=> myArray[0] = "text1", myArray[1] = "text2", myArray[2] = "text3"
```

What should I enter in the "???"? Or is there a different approach I should use?

*Making ")(" a separator won't work as I want to split the array with a variety of separators such as ">" making it very unpractical to list every possible combination of separators*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.split(/[()]+/).filter(function(e) { return e; });
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsNx7/)**.

Comment: Please provide an explanation, without one this answer isn't especially helpful.

Comment: I think the code says it all. This is exactly what I was looking for. We can also use "(text1)(text2)(text3)".split(/[()]+/).filter(String); to get rid of that nasty little empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Using split between specific characters without losing any characters is not possible with JavaScript, because you would need a lookbehind for that (which is not supported).
But since you seem to want the texts *inside* the parentheses, instead of splitting you could just `match` the longest-possible string not containing parentheses:

```
myArray = "(text1)(text2)(text3)".match(/[^()]+/g)
```

Comment: this answer is the most sensible for behaviour OP wants, (not a simple string split) but will fail for e.g. `"(text(1)(text(2)"`. You _can_ make this match the opening parentheses, too, then `map` them out; `.match(/\([^)]+/g).map(function (e) {return e.slice(1);});`

Comment: @PaulS sure, but that seems rather invalid. and things with proper nesting can't be matched anyway. I mean, why support `(text(1)(text(2)` but not `(1)text)(2)text)` or `(te(1)xt)(te(2)xt)`?

Comment: True. I was trying to think how to do all of them without needing a loop, but a second `(` defiantly would not be the end of the section, whereas a second `)` could be. It isn't the biggest issue in the world though.

Comment: @PaulS. allowing arbitrary nesting is the biggest issue in the world, if you want to solve it with a JavaScript regex ;)